# Missing binaries for postgres_fdw and uuid-ossp

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I'm upgrading my database from 10.4 to 11.3 but when performing the check when using pg_upgrade, I am getting the following errors:

```
could not load library "$libdir/uuid-ossp": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory
could not load library "$libdir/postgres_fdw": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgres_fdw": No such file or directory
```

I am using CentOS 7 and to see if I need to create the extension first, I tried the following and got the following error:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/pgapp/postgresql/11.3/share/extension/postgres_fdw.control": No such file or directory
```

So it doesn't seem like the FDW binaries were loaded when I did the yum install documented on the postgres page.   Is there a way to install these files separately or is there another way to get this to work so that I can finish my upgrade?

Comment: On Linux you typically you need to install the extension separately: `yum install postgresql-contrib` (or something similar)

Comment: Thank you so much a_horse_with_no_name, that did the trick.  I had to make sure I used yum install postgresql11-contrib because without the number it installed version 9.2 for some reason but everything is working now.

Comment: How do I give you credit for the help?  Sorry for the newbie question